# NIFI AUTHENTICATION

Tags: security, ldap, storage, apache-nifi

Is there anyway that we can give security measures for nifi, like any username and password for the nifi UI page. And also anyway to give storage for the configuration made in the NIFI UI page.

Need some suggestion on this issue.

Comment: You can either configure SSL or User Authentication or both. Did you look at the official documentation? 

http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#security_configuration

Answer (score 2):

All user authentication and authorization mechanisms are only available once TLS is enabled. This was an intentional design decision because entering sensitive user credentials over a plaintext HTTP connection is unsafe and exposes the user to many opportunities to have those credentials, which unfortunately they may reuse for other services, stolen.

After enabling TLS for the NiFi application, LDAP, Kerberos, OpenID Connect, Knox, and client certificates are all available as authentication mechanisms.

Comment: So is it possible in if my nifi is in kubernetes  ?

Comment: Yes, many users run NiFi on Kubernetes with authentication enabled.

Comment: Can you share me any way to create the follow steps.. ? or anywhere i can refer so that i can make it work.?

Comment: The [Admin Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#user_authentication) and [User Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#UI-with-multi-tenant-authorization) provide instructions on configuring user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

With the default settings you can point a web browser at
https://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi

The default installation generates a random username and password, writing the generated values to the application log. The application log is located in `logs/nifi-app.log` under the installation directory. The log file will contain lines with Generated Username [USERNAME] and Generated Password [PASSWORD] indicating the credentials needed for access. Search the application log for those lines and record the generated values in a secure location.

The following command can be used to change the username and password:

```
$ ./bin/nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials <username> <password>
```